# Arduino and raspberry pi communication via USB

Tags: python, usb, raspberry-pi2, arduino-uno

I have a problem for communication between arduino and raspberry pi.

Arduino code:

```
char intput_arduino;
int rand_value;
void setup(){
   Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop(){
 if(Serial.available() > 0){
   intput_arduino = Serial.read();
   Serial.flush();
   rand_value = intput_arduino - '0';
   String sending_data = "S, " + String(rand_value) + ", " + "E";
   Serial.println(sending_data);
   delay(1000);
   }
}
```

Raspberry pi 2 model B Python code:

```
import time
import random
ser = serial.Serial('dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
time.sleep(5)
rand_value=random.randint(1,3)
ser.write(str(rand_value))
print "read : %s" % ser.readline()
print
```

When I checked serial monitor from arduino, it read correct value from raspberry pi.

However, when arduino sends back to raspberry pi, raspberry pi cannot read the value.

It stopped ser.readline()

How can I fix it..?

Comment: Is this a serial or usb communication?

Comment: Need response delay. Can't write and read same time. use "delay(1000);" on arduino side, where delay of python side ?

Comment: Can you give me sample code??
For python side, do I need inWaiting() function for delay??